# Why can't I connect to device in Google Cloud IOT Core through MQTT?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, paho

I want to connect my backend on Spring boot to one of the devices in my hardware setup in Google Cloud Iot-Core. I basically copied [this github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/iot/api-client/manager/src/main/java/com/example/cloud/iot/examples/MqttExample.java) and adjusted the authentication and connection options. When I run my program it throws this exception:

*Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient]: Factory method 'connectToMqttClient' threw exception; nested exception is Incorrect username or password (4)*

To create password I use this method

```
private static String createJwtRsa(String projectId, String privateKeyFile)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    DateTime now = new DateTime();

    JwtBuilder jwtBuilder =
            Jwts.builder()
                    .setIssuedAt(now.toDate())
                    .setExpiration(now.plusMinutes(20).toDate())
                    .setAudience(projectId);

    byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(privateKeyFile));
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    return jwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, kf.generatePrivate(spec)).compact();
}
```

I had an issue with privateKeyFile format. On Iot-core the device has public key of RS256_X509

[image]

But Spring Boot only allows RS256_PKCS8 key formats, so I had to do this:

1. I generated key of format X509 *openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout rsa_private.pem -out rsa_cert.pem -subj "/CN=unused"* it also generated certificate rsa_cer.pem
2. I converted the key to PKCS8 format *openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in rsa_private.pem -out private_key.der -nocrypt*
3. The certificate I added as public key in Iot-core and rsa_private.der I used in my createJwtRsa method

Since then I get the exception: Incorrect Username and password. What can I do to fix it?

Edit:

I also tried generating normal RSA256 key and convert it to PKCS8 format, and I get the same exception. The same with ES256 key

Comment: Looking at the code, it states that you must provide `connectOptions.setUserName("unused");` for the password to be sent along, even when the username is not used.  Are you sending it?

Also I see 2 public certificates in that image you used.  Seeing that they are named the same, could it potentially be checking against the wrong one?

Comment: Hi, I am only generating 1 certificate  rsa_cert.pem which I copy to Iot Core device RSA public key. Atlhough I do have 2 private keys. I only use the PKCS8 converted one in generating jwt private. And yes I have setup username unused as it was presented in gcloud repository
 https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/iot/api-client/manager/src/main/java/com/example/cloud/iot/examples/MqttExample.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue! the clientId was incorrect

```
final String mqttClientId = String.format("projects/%s/locations/%s/registries/%s/devices/%s",
options.projectId, options.cloudRegion, options.registryId, options.gatewayId);
```

My gatewayId was an empty string because we don't have a gateway created on Iot Core, we connect directly to devices.
So today I set gatewayId to deviceId and the backend connected successfully to the device.
So now the line looks like this

```
final String mqttClientId = String.format("projects/%s/locations/%s/registries/%s/devices/%s",options.projectId, 
 options.cloudRegion, options.registryId, options.deviceId);
```